# I am trying to remove NA values from a row in R but getting "replacement has 863 rows, data has 940"

Tags: r

I have a dataset called "daily_activity". I am trying to remove the rows from the column called "TotalSteps" with values of "0".
First, I converted them to values of NA. But when I try to remove them I get an error message.

```
daily_activity$TotalSteps[daily_activity$TotalSteps <=0] <- NA
daily_activity$TotalSteps <- na.omit(daily_activity$TotalSteps)
```

But I get the error message "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, TotalSteps, value = c(13162L, 10735L,  :
replacement has 863 rows, data has 940.
I am very new to R so I apologize if this is a dumb question. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: See the “complete.cases()” function

Answer (score 0):

The daily_activity is a data.frame with 940 rows.
TotalSteps is a column of that dataframe, so it has also 940 rows (cells).
When you remove the NA values from the column TotalSteps, then the result would be a column of 863 rows (cells).
Nevertheless, the dataframe must consist of columns with the same number rows (cells), thus the error you get.